# How to use IF and CAST function in COGNOS?

Tags: if-statement, casting, cognos, cognos-10

IF [Business Unit] = 'Air Export' then '1'
ELSE [Business Unit]
END

A Business Unit comprises of 
 - Air Export
 - Air Import
 - Sea Export
 - Sea Import

My objective is to portray the transit target days for **Air Export only** which is always 1 day.

Currently, I'm doing for a data item called "**Transit Target 1**".

There will be a data item called "**Total Transit Target**" which comprises of "Transit Target 1","Transit Target 2" and "Transit Target 3".

I would like to **cast '1' as a float** for me to do a calculation for "Total Transit Target" later on.

How do I go about doing this? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to run into to problems casting your result. The problem is the result as coded will result in five possible values:

- Air Export
- Air Import
- Sea Export
- Sea Import
- 1

Only the last value can be successfully cast to a numeric (or float) type.

What I would do is modify your IF...THEN to output either 1 or 0, both integers and thus already in the proper form for cacluation:

```
IF ([Business Unit] = 'Air Export')
THEN (1) 
ELSE (0)
```

Note that there are no quotes around either result values. They will be of type integer and ready for use in caclulations

Some tips with IF..THEN in Cognos. All conditions and results have to be wrapped in parentheses. Also, there has to be an ELSE clause. Lastly, there is no END. That's used in CASE statements.

Comment: Hi Johnsoium. Thanks for highlighting. I somehow realised that I didn't use paranthesis and it then works. I also saw your solution. I did that way as well but I somehow still need to reflect the business unit if it's not Air Export (due to the Key Account Manager's request). Just wondering if there's really a way to do this. If it's impossible, I'll take it. But i just want to explore the possibilities.

Comment: You should use a switch statement in that case. In Cognos a switch will be:
case
when ( [Business Unit] = 'Air Export' ) then ( 1 )
when ( [Business Unit] = 'Air Import' ) then ( 0 )
end
You could add as may when's as you need

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to sound like I'm being passively-aggressively unhelpfully helpful but I'd think that I might want to start by exploring the CAST function.

Where are you going to get the other values for "Total Transit Target"?  i.e. where's "Transit Target 2" and "Transit Target 3" coming from?  Other calculations based on business unit? Would a case function be more useful than IF?

Who is determining the target? Could target values change for an object? Could it be possible that air export in future could be another value, at least for some instances?  Wouldn't it be better if this information was captured in your db, at least because it would be visible, usable in other report contexts, and maintainable?   Plus save a wee bit on processing.

Comment: Where are you going to get the other values for "Total Transit Target"? --> As mentioned, "Total Transit Target" will be a sum of "Transit Target 1" + "Transit Target 2" + "Transit Target 3"

Comment: Who is determining the target? --> A Key Account Manager has the KPI set.
Could target values change for an object? --> It is fixed.
Could it be possible that air export in future could be another value, at least for some instances? --> Not sure what you mean here.
Would a case function be more useful than IF? --> I believe a case function does not support float data type as I have target transit days of 1.5 which is one and a half days.